# HTML5 Audio and Video elements keep popping Chrome's permission

Tags: asp.net, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I have a `<video>` and `<audio>` element in a simple aspx page.
I have a script that loads on body load event, which instantiates a recorder JS class.
Whenever the page posts-back, I get a permissions message from Chrome:

[image]

Clicking "Allow" only allows once. On the next postback, the message appears again. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Note: This happens only in my production environment. When I run this (using Chrome) in my QA environment, I just clicked "allow" once and the message does not appear any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by switching page to HTTPS.